# Trying to do 2D to 3D from a 3/4 view image

Tags: modeling

[image]

So I've been trying to turn this image into a 3D model for about 3 days now and I've watched a lot of 2D to 3D videos to try to find a work around but no luck. To me the issue comes from the perspective that the image is drawn in, because from all the videos I've seen they've all used side and front views.

Comment: That is just 3d modelling you are talking about. I am afraid you might find that there is no magic shortcut or button that you could press, instead this is just work that has to be done, but it also requires learning to do it first. It's best to face it - acquiring the needed skills cannot be skipped and might take a few months to a few years. It is also not something that can be answered in an answer on Blender Stack Exchange.

Comment: it would be difficult to model the character using only this image, it's better to use side view and front view.  (top view and back view are great too, but not necissarily required.) :)

Comment: Thank you @MartinZ and Millard. MartinZ I'll take more time and build the skills. Millard yeah, that's what I figured but I had this drawn for me so I don't have any other views of it. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might help to create a basic shape of the creature from spheres first, you can even connect them via booleans (BoolTools addon auto join is great) after and then sculpt from the rough shape

Comment: Thanks @InTheBeef, I'll give it a try.